# Is there a R command for testing the difference in coefficients of two linear regression​s?

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients

I am looking for a R command to test the difference of two linear regressoon betas. Lets say I have data $x_1, x_2...x_{n＋1}$.

$\beta_1$ is obtained from regressing $x_1$ to $x_n$ onto $1$ to $n$.

$\beta_2$ is obtained from regressing $x_2$ to $x_{n＋1}$ onto $1$ to $n$.

Is there a way in `R` to test whether $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are statistically different?

Edit:

Here is a clearer problem statement:

I changed the notation for data from $x$ to $z$...

That's it. Should be very clear now... Thanks!

Data observations: $z_1, z_2, ..., z_{n+1}$

```
y1 = z_1,z_2,.........  z_n 
y2 = z_2, z_3,......... z_{n+1}

x1 = 1, ..., n
x2 = 1, ..., n

y1 = A1+ x1 * B1 + epsilon_1
y2 = A2 + x2 * B2 + epsilon_2
```

H0: B1 and B2 are statistically significally different...

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your notation. Is "x1, x2...x(n＋1)" referring to random variables or observations? And what is the significance of "(n+1)"?

Comment: Presumably you mean "H0: B1 and B2 are the same" and you are looking for statistically significant evidence to reject H0.

Comment: Are you trying to model a structural change in the data? If so, then the package [strucchange](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/index.html) might be appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

You can stack the data so that you have $x_1 ... x_n$ followed by $x_2 ... x_{n+1}$ in one column, then the next column would have $1 ... n$ repeated twice, then a third column would have $0$'s coresponding to the 1st group and $1$'s for the second group.  Now do the regression including an interaction between the $1 ... n$ and the $0/1$ group variable.  The slope for the interaction represents the difference between the 2 slopes you are interested in, testing the interaction will test if the slopes are different.  However, the standard regression assumptions may not hold here (your data certainly is not independent), so you should do some type of simulation under the null hypothesis to determine the critical region to use to determine significance.

Here is some example R code:

```
y1 <- anscombe$y1[order(anscombe$x1)]
y2 <- anscombe$y2[order(anscombe$x2)]


df1 <- data.frame( y=c(y1[-11], y1[-1]), x=rep(1:10, 2), g=rep(0:1, each=10))
df2 <- data.frame( y=c(y2[-11], y2[-1]), x=rep(1:10, 2), g=rep(0:1, each=10))

fit1 <- lm( y ~ x*g, data=df1 )
fit2 <- lm( y ~ x*g, data=df2 )

tmpfun <- function(n, beta, sigma) {
    x <- 1:n
    y <- beta*x + rnorm(n,0,sigma)
    df <- data.frame( y=c(y[-n],y[-1]), x=rep(seq(to=n-1), 2), 
        g=rep(0:1, each=n-1) )
    fit <- lm( y~x*g, data=df )
    coef(fit)[4]
}

tmpfit <- lm(y1 ~ seq_along(y1))
out1 <- replicate(1000, tmpfun(11, coef(tmpfit)[2], summary(tmpfit)$sigma) )
hist(out1)
abline( v=quantile(out1, c(0.025, 0.975)), col='red')
abline( v=coef(fit1)[4], col='blue' )

tmpfit <- lm(y2 ~ seq_along(y1))
out2 <- replicate(1000, tmpfun(11, coef(tmpfit)[2], summary(tmpfit)$sigma) )
hist(out2)
abline( v=quantile(out2, c(0.025, 0.975)), col='red')
abline( v=coef(fit2)[4], col='blue' )
```

If you tell us more about what you are trying to accomplish we may be able to suggest better methods.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my previous problem statement: I changed the notation for data from x to z...
 
That's it. Should be very clear now... Thanks!
 
Data: z1, z2, ..., z_{n+1}
 
y1 = z_1,z_2,.........  z_n 
y2 = z_2, z_3,......... z_{n+1}
 
x1 = 1, ..., n
x2 = 1, ..., n
 
y1 = A1+ x1 * B1 + epsilon_1
y2 = A2 + x2 * B2 + epsilon_2

H0: B1 and B2 are statistically significally different...

Comment: "Stacking" the data in this manner is clever.  However, that induces *perfect* correlations among many of the responses.  Because your model does not appear to account for that, its estimates look problematic--and even if they are correct, the covariance matrix, p-values, intervals, and associated hypothesis tests will certainly be wrong.  This problem is likely so severe that "your data certainly is not independent" doesn't look like a sufficiently strong caution.

Comment: @Greg Snow: Can you explain what `out1` & `out2` in your code are?

Comment: @user603, The `tmpfun` function returns the coefficient for the interaction in the analysis of the simulated data.  `out1` and `out2` are vectors with the returns from `tmpfun` from 1,000 runs of the simulation (so vectors of interaction coefficients from 1,000 simulation runs).

Comment: @GregSnow; thanks. What is the difference between them? I mean why do you have two?

Comment: @user603, they are based on different models.  In the code `tmpfit` is fit using `y1` then `out1` is created based on that model, then `tmpfit` is refit using `y2` and `out2` is created.  I probably should have used different names for the 2 fits to make it clearer.

Comment: @GregSnow Thanks. Could you also perhaps also explain what those two models are (it seems they only differ in how the response is sorted, is this correct?).

Comment: @user603, plot the 2 y-variables.  One is more linear than the other, so the more linear one does not reject that the slope changes and the less linear one does.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing something like:

```
set.seed(1)

x1<-rnorm(100,1) 
x2<-rnorm(100,mean(x1))
y<-rnorm(100, mean(x1+x2)+rnorm(100))

fit1<-lm(y~x1, data)
fit2<-lm(x1~x2, data)
```

If so, you might be able to get away with:

```
d<-coef(fit1)[2] - coef(fit2)[2] 

coef(fit)[2] is the second coefficient in the model, i.e. the beta

var1<-summary(fit1)$coef[4]^2
```

This is the fourth coefficient in the summary, or the se of beta1

```
var2<-summary(fit2)$coef[4]^2


ztest<- d / sqrt(var1+var2)

1-pnorm(ztest)

       x1 
0.5918211
```

this was my answer, so I would say there is no difference, but beta1 was -.11 and beta 2 was .-07, so they're pretty similar.

Comment: Welcome to the site Corey. Please use the markdown formatting available (see the buttons at the top of editor when inserting your answer), or take a look at the advanced markdown editing help, http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help. In particular, it is much easier to read code when it is formatted appropriately.